# How can I add header conditionally in nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx

How can I add header conditionally in nginx(1.4.6 ubuntu) configuration?

At first I tried like this.

```
 location / {
      add_header X-TEST-0 always-0;

      set $true 1;
      if ($true) {
          add_header X-TEST-1 only-true;
      }

      add_header X-TEST-2 always-2;
  }
```

Although I expected my nginx set all header(X-TEST-0,1,2), it added header only X-TEST-1.

Next I tried like this.

```
 location / {
      add_header X-TEST-0 always-0;

      ##set $true 1;
      ##if ($true) {
      ##    add_header X-TEST-1 only-true;
      ##}

      add_header X-TEST-2 always-2;
  }
```

My nginx added header X-TEST-1 and X-TEST-2 as I expected.

My quastions are...

1. How can I add header conditionally?
2. Why does nginx add only X-TEST-1 with my first example above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a classic example from [If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)

Comment: You could use `set` inside `if`. Or use `map` directive.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I could get all I wanted in the page you linked.

Comment: Use `map` as described in http://serverfault.com/a/598106/119913

Comment: Thanks @KevinSmyth ! I will try it later.

Answer (score 16):

This is simple if you think differently and use a map.

```
map $variable  $headervalue {
    1        only-true;
    default  '';
}

# ...later...
location / {
    add_header X-TEST-1   $headervalue;
}
```

If $variable is 1, $headervalue will be set and hence the header will be added.
By default $headervalue will be empty and the header will not be added.

This is efficient because Nginx only evaluates the map when it's needed (when it gets to a point where $headervalue is referenced).

See similar: https://serverfault.com/questions/598085/nginx-add-header-conditional-on-an-upstream-http-variable

Comment: I believe it's important to add map is only valid on http context. I was using it on server context (right above the location directive) and got an error about `"map" directive is not allowed here`. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

Answer (score 6):

I used [lua nginx module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) to solve a similar problem:

```
localtion / {
  header_filter_by_lua_block {
    ngx.header["X-TEST-0"] = "always-0";
    # example of conditional header
    if ngx.req.get_method() == ngx.HTTP_POST {
      ngx.header["X-TEST-1"] = "only if POST request";
    }
    ngx.header["X-TEST-2"] = "always-2";
  }
}
```

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#header_filter_by_lua_block
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful information. It could be a solution for the nginx user who don't mind to use the modules which is not the standard of nginx.I voted +1.

Comment: If anybody is trying something like this, be aware that the correct lua syntax is possibly `if ... then ... end` :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way, I wanted to print a specified country symbol
first, I map the `geo` if certain IP's in the server blocks

```
geo $CNTRY {
    default '';
    192.104.49.0/24 ML;
    192.104.46.0/24 ML;
    192.104.47.0/24 ML;
}
```

Then I simply add it to  server block, (anywhere doesn't matter)

```
add_header x-CNTRY $CNTRY;
```