# nginx - add_header gets overwritten

Tags: nginx, cookies, cors

I'm having a very hard time understanding exactly when nginx overwrites my add_header directives.

I have the following:

```
include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/ihc.example.com;
location = /auth {
    proxy_pass http://sso.example.com/auth/login;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
location / {
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $saved_set_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
        add_header Set-Cookie $saved_set_cookie; #I don't see this header in the response
        proxy_pass http://ihc.example.com;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/ihc.example.com_location;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `auth_request_set $saved_set_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;` cookie doesn't appear in the response.

Now if I remove the `include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/ihc.example.com_location;` line, it will appear, but this file contains a shared CORS fix that I would really, really like to keep:

```
if ($cors = 'trueGET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin; #I see this header in the response
[...]
```

How can I achieve both without having to repeat the CORS headers in every location? And what is causing this to become overwritten? As I read the documentation, `location` should overwrite `server`, but in this case, what is causing this new "scope"?

Comment: OK, am deleting my answer because I think I misunderstood the problem.                    Will post a new if/when I have time look back and it and can figure out what's happening. Hopefully in the mean time somebody else here beats me to it..

Comment: @sideshowbarker: Probably me who wasn't being clear. I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on here. I will investigate a bit more.

Comment: Still not sure what's going on. I copied the CORS headers directly into the `location /` block, and everything works now. As I see it, either the `if` or the `include`counts as a seperate scope. I hope someone can elaborate.

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467671/how-can-i-add-header-conditionally-in-nginx-configuration/34295867#34295867 has a possible solution to this, which amounts to using the Lua nginx module https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module. So if that’s feasible in your case, you might want to explore that. In the mean time, it’s become clear to me from doing some further reading that the behavior described in the question here is expected behavior in nginx given the idiosyncrasies of how the `if` conditional works in nginx. I’ll post a summary here after reading a bit more

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017524/how-to-add-headers-in-nginx-only-sometimes/31026765#31026765 has another solution that may work for your case and that doesn’t rely on needing to install the Lua nginx module

Comment: See https://agentzh.blogspot.jp/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html, which explains the cause here in the clearest language I’ve found so far: *“Nginx's "if" block effectively creates a (nested) location block and once the "if" condition matches, only the content handler of the inner location block (i.e., the "if" block) will be executed.”*

Comment: Thanks. It would indeed make sense if the `if` creates a new scope, but now it doesn't make sense to me that it works when I keep the ifs, but don't use include. I found a work around, feel free to post the links as an answer, as my original question was really what counted as a scope.

Comment: OK, promoted my comments here to being an answer. But please consider also post the details of your workaround as an answer as well—even if it’s ugly—because I’m personally very interested what you ended up doing to get it working, and I reckon others here will be as well (now and in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root cause of my issue:

[Ifs are evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

Apparently, using `if` statements in location blocks leads to unspecified behaviours. Unfortunately for me, this means rethinking my entire setup, and potentially switching to OpenResty instead.