# nginx does not add my custom header to response

Tags: nginx, http-headers, nginx-config

I have a rather simple nginx config, which serves a static file as "endpoint". However, the custom header under `/version` I want to add, is not added.

Can anyone tell me why?

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  map $http_accept $img_suffix {
    "~*webp"  ".webp";
    "~*jxr"   ".jxr";
  }
  server {
    server_tokens off;

    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location = /version {
      default_type application/json;

      # add test header
      add_header "TEST" "TEST";

      # CORS
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control, Last-Modified";
      if ($request_method = GET) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
      }
      if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, OPTIONS, HEAD";
        return 200;
      }

      index version;
    }

    location / {
      # CORS
      if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
      }

      if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD";
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
        return 200;
      }

      add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=31449600'; # one year
      include /etc/nginx/security-headers.conf;
      try_files $uri index.html =404;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have `add_header` as part of `if` block. `if` is part of the rewrite module.

It's an classic example of [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

You could probably use `map` module to set variables and then use them with your add_header directive. There are other options suggested here as well.

[How can I add header conditionally in nginx configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467671/how-can-i-add-header-conditionally-in-nginx-configuration)

Comment: Thanks, what a mess ... removing the "ifs" does help.